# Vertical space added automatically around a div in grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid, spacing

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd" "as mn";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header { grid-area: hd; }
aside  { grid-area: as; }

main {
  grid-area: mn;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
}

main > div {
  height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

I want to know how the vertical space around the `div` was added automatically. I know it can be fixed by setting `repeat(3, auto)` to `repeat(3, min-content)`, but what exactly caused the spacing issue?

Comment: edited answer please look into it!

Answer (score 1):

## I hope i can clear this doubt by this 4 snippets

> Run all this 4 code,and note the vertical height

> I have highlighted with colors for all three code-for you to understand

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd" "as mn";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green; 
}

header { grid-area: hd; }
aside  { grid-area: as; }

main {
  grid-area: mn;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

main > div {
  height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>

  
  </main>
</body>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd" "as mn";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green; 
}

header { grid-area: hd; }
aside  { grid-area: as; }

main {
  grid-area: mn;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

main > div {
  height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  
  </main>
</body>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd" "as mn";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green; 
}

header { grid-area: hd; }
aside  { grid-area: as; }

main {
  grid-area: mn;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

main > div {
  height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    
  </main>
</body>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd" "as mn";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green; 
}

header { grid-area: hd; }
aside  { grid-area: as; }

main {
  grid-area: mn;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

main > div {
  height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
  </main>
</body>
```

> Understood the difference?

> But I will say, the difference is only in the *number* of `div` I put in the `main`,it changes the space(*inversely proportional*)

> So the reason is auto tries to give the space it can afford, and so if it can give more space (more space *if less* div) it will leave some *leftover space* in top and bottom of div

> while `min-content` gives space that is only *needed* by `div`

> By now after reading these you would have known that,

> leftoverspace = (`HeightOfMain`-(`HeightOfDiv` * `NumberOfDiv`))/`NumberOfDiv`

> the above formula gives space for top+bottom of div if you want for only to then,

> leftoverspace = (`HeightOfMain`-(`HeightOfDiv` * `NumberOfDiv`))/(`NumberOfDiv` * 2)
> **Note that number of div is number of vertical div and not total,so if you take my last code snippet,`number of div`=4**

> in your case

- `HeightOfMain`=100vh
- `NumberOfDiv`= 1
- `HeightOfDiv` = 3em

> so `leftoverspace` = (`100vh`-(`3em` * `1`))/(`1` * 2)

Comment: Is there some way to know how much space will be vacant when less items are there? (like not on inspection, but from the code)

Comment: @book-of-flames yes i have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You're applying a fixed height and width to your `div`, that's why the rest of the grid cell contains that empty space.

```css
main > div {
  height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
}
```

If you want the `div` to fill out the whole grid cell, then you should set both `height` and `width` to 100%.

```css
main > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Your modified snippet:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1em 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd" "as mn";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header { grid-area: hd; }
aside  { grid-area: as; }

main {
  grid-area: mn;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
}

main > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted the reason why is there vertical empty space surrounding the div. That was my question

Comment: I clarified my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, to some extent. Is there some way to actually know how much space will be vacant?

Comment: You mean the size of the grid cells? You have this style defined: `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr)` so the size of each grid is `a fraction`. This needs more explanations, here's a good article: https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/

Comment: Alternatively, you could set a fixed grid cell size, by using `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 200px)`.

Comment: I think what they are asking is why does the single `<div/>` element inside the first grid row/column have extra space around it, as you would assume the rows would only take up the height of their content as `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto)` would lead you to believe. It's an odd behaviour for sure. I'm not certain myself, but I do know that setting anything to `auto` can have strange consequences

Comment: @BookOfFlames If I could answer your question `what exactly caused the spacing issue` then please accept the answer to improve the visibility.

Comment: I still am not able to understand how to calculate the empty space surrounding the div (the vertical spacing)